# Converting georeferenced .pdf to .tiff in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, geotiff-tiff, geopdf

I am attempting to convert a USGS georeferenced pdf to a tiff.  I found this help page, which looks pretty simple: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/pdf-to-tiff.htm#GUID-E7643B8C-5493-4E07-83F8-6322307415D2

Except my Conversion Tools do not have "From PDF" (I am running Arcmap 10.2.2).

Does anyone have advice on how to troubleshoot or use another method?

Comment: The pdf to tif tool was added in 10.3 to ArcGIS.  It is not available in ArcGIS Pro.  Production Mapping extension may have had the tool in 10.2.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53023/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-pdf-to-arcmap-as-data for other methods.

Comment: USGS documentation: http://nationalmap.gov/ustopo/documents/ustopo2gtif_current.pdf

Comment: GDAL_Translate will do it (see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Convert_GeoPDF_to_GeoTiff), and if you're afraid of DOS it can be done in QGIS (install required), GDAL can be downloaded and used from a USB stick in DOS (no install required).

Comment: The GDAL answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121226/ and also related http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68413/